# Separate Word chart's data from Excel file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2013, charts, microsoft-word-2013, links

There is a certain chart in Excel that I cannot exactly replicate in Word, so I copied the chart into a Word document. However, now the chart's data are tied to the Excel document I copied the chart from. I'd like to separate the data from the Excel file so the chart's data is stored in the same way it would be stored if I had created a chart in Word from scratch - within the Word file.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your chart in Excel -- it will be easier later if you have the data in one sheet and the chart in another. Make sure the sheet with the chart is visible and that the chart is in the top left corner of the sheet (again, this makes things easier later on)
2. Save the .XLSX wherever is convenient and close it
3. Open the Word file
4. Drag the Excel file onto the Word document ***or*** go to `Insert -> Text -> Object -> Object`, then click on the "Create from File" tab, browse to your file and, making sure the "Link to File checkbox is **unchecked**, click OK.
5. If you right-click on the chart, you should be able to edit it by choosing `Worksheet Object -> Open` in the pop-up menu

Answer (score 0):

You can unlink the Excel file, but then you cannot edit your chart data.

1. On File menu, bottom right area (Office 2016) there's a button "Edit Links to Files".
   [image: Edit Links to Files]
2. Choose your connection and click on "Break Link".
   [image: Break Link]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the chart's data is going to be edited monthly, which means I cannot lose the ability to edit that data.

Comment: In this case, IMO, it is best to keep files liked. If you separate them, there is more area for human error when trying to manually copy data to Word.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my previous comment, but I'll be making copies of this file, and each time I make a copy, the link remains, so every time I'm editing a copy of this file, I'm also editing the linked spreadsheet that previous copies of the document use. This is pretty much the reason why I wanted to unlink them.

Comment: Then [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1418491#1418695) may help. It kind of creates an Excel file INSIDE the Word file. So every copy of the Word file will have it's own internal embedded Excel.